# How can I parse this string to NSDate with NSDateFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have a date as a string in the format:

```
2010-12-31 20:21:00 +0200
```

What I'd like to do is parse this using NSDateFormatter to an NSDate object but I'm having difficulty matching the format properly.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.alloc.init;
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
[dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2010-12-31 20:21:00 +0200"] // returns nil ;
```

Can anybody help me find the correct format? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.alloc.init;
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:NSTimeZone.localTimeZone];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2010-12-31 20:21:00 +0200"];
  NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

And I just want you to know, kind sir, that my eyes bleed when I see this `NSDateFormatter.alloc.init`

Comment: lol - I had originally written this: `NSDateFormatter.new` but feared criticism. I'm actually building the app in Ruby using Rubymotion so the "dot" method syntax is all I use :)

Comment: Thanks for the help though-  I don't now why I had those apostrophes around the `Z`

Comment: You should really consider using "dot" notation when calling upon properties and using square brackets to send messages like alloc, init, new etc. I mean you're using `setDateFormat:` when you could use `formatter.dateFormat`, and both are absolutely fine, but the more of such diverse code is in there, the less readable it is. Anyways, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];

NSString * currentDate = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:currentDate];
```